# Difficulty with 2D Vector Class in C++, Executable Crashes and Won't run

Tags: c++

I am currently at the beginning of working on an assignment for a class to replicate the sliding brick puzzle. It has been a few years since I have use C++, so I am attempting to relearn and do the assignment all at once. I study bioengineering and use MATLAB all of the time, but its also hard for me to adjust to C++ in the few computer science classes that I take.

My question is regarding the load function. This is supposed to load in a provided file that has the width and height of the puzzle in the first row and integers representing to puzzle pieces and spaces in the following rows. When I test it with a given file, the .exe file crashes and no errors are given, so I can't tell what is wrong. If I comment out lines 31-32 (width = str[0]; height = str[2]), the program does not crash, but I cannot tell what is wrong with these lines. I have provided my code below for your reference. An example file to be loaded by the function is:

5,4,/n 1,-1,-1,1,1,\n 1,0,3,4,1,\n 1,0,2,2,1,\n 1,1,1,1,1,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class SBP
{
public:
    vector< vector<int> > state;
    int width; //columns
    int height; //rows

    void load(string filename);
    void display();
    SBP clone();
    bool complete();

};

void SBP::load(string filename)
{
    int rownum = 1;
    char n;
    string str;
    ifstream file(filename.c_str());
    getline(file, str);
    width = str[0];
    height = str[2];
    while (getline(file, str))
    {
        vector<int> row;
        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
        {
            n = str[i];
            if (n != ',')
            {
                if (n == '-')
                {
                    row.push_back((str[i + 1] - '0')*(-1));
                    i = i + 1;
                }
                else
                    row.push_back(n - '0');
            }
        }
        state.push_back(row);
        printf("The row is: %i %i %i %i %i", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
        rownum = rownum + 1;
    }
    printf("File has been loaded.\n\n");
}

void SBP::display()
{
    int num;
    printf("The state of the game is: \n");
    printf("%i,%i,\n", width, height);
    for (int r = 0; r < height; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < width; c++)
        {
            num = state[r][c];
            printf("%i,", num);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string filename = argv[1];
    SBP puzzle, clonestate;
    puzzle.load(filename);
    puzzle.display();
}
```

I hope someone can help me. This is just the beginning of the assignment and I'm not able to move on until I get this fixed. Thank you.

Comment: You know where the problem manifests, great start, but you can get a much better look at what is really happening by running the program in your development environment's debugger, placing a breakpoint on the line in question, and inspecting the state of the variables involved when you reach that line.

Comment: There's a lot of blind assumption about what you're reading. You might consider adding some error checking to validate that what you think you're reading is what you actually are reading.

Comment: `width = str[0];` isn't going to work. It will set `width` to the integer value of the first character on the line. This will not be 5. It will be the numeric code for the character '5', which is most likely 53. Quick fix for this is `width = str[0]-'0';` this subtracts the numeric code for '0' from the character and, in any sane character encoding, give you the number you want.